# emacs python, search by class name

Tags: python, emacs

I want to search by class name within my project. For those who have used pycharms, their search by class name is that I want.

I'm using helm-projectile, it'll be great if there was a helm-projectile-find-class

Comment: Never actually used PyCharm, but I feel quite comfortable with semantic + speedbar. You can not search classes in a whole project but you can easily browse names in a single python module. I think that you may reach your goal by adding EDE project manager to your configuration (all included in emacs24) .

Comment: semantic was exactly what I was looking for! Do you know how to load semanticdb each time emacs starts?

Comment: Just add `(semantic-mode 1)` to your .emacs.
I prefer not to load it every time because it's quite resource consuming, especially when you open a file it never have seen before.